# Importing a React component from one page to another on Djit.su?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a personal portfolio page on [Djit.su](https://djit.su) and I would like to know if I can import a button component from one page to another?

Here is the page with the Button

https://djit.su/djXiGiR1w7gxwjQfdplWG

and here is the Header component in which I would like to import.

https://djit.su/duQunFB96wDSgVdWap2Gj

I've tried to import using the page title

`import CoolButton from 'djXiGiR1w7gxwjQfdplWG'`

but that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated...